# Image does not resize in smaller browser

Tags: css

I am trying to place a image on the bottom right corner of my page and have it always be there. I have managed to do this but I have a problem when making the browser window smaller (which also is a problem while looking at it in different advices with smaller screens). When I make the browser smaller the image stays in the same size, and eventually overlaps over the other items (like my menu for example). Is there anyway to make that the image automatically becomes smaller together with the browser?

The css code I have used to place the image on the bottom right corner looks like this:

```
display:block;
float:right;
bottom:0;
right:0;
width:340px;
```

The image is a png image placed inside a div in my html.

I hope someone can understand what I mean and help me with this!

Comment: You need absolute positioning to accomplish this, not FLOATS.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the image a percentage for a width instead of a pixel width.  It will then resize when you resize the window.  Try setting `width: 20%` as a starting point and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<html>
<style>
img{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto; 
}
</style>
<body>
<img src="slide2.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

resizing browser also resizes image, and is always at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Using `%` values for the width and height of the image should work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floating for this case, your positioning should be absolute and don't set pixel-based sizes. If you want to set its size, you can do it by percentage, however, maybe the best solution would be to have separate themes for separate screen sizes.